# issue with changing file element

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with Breast Cancer Wisconsin (Diagnostic) Data Set and trying to use KNN in it with Jupyter. I converted the file wdbc.data into csv and swapped M and B with 1 and 0 respectively using the find and replace in Libreoffice[[image]][[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdQbZ.png). However, after doing so the vales in the file change as shown in the screenshot. Any solution?

--I'm new with python and machine learning. Please excuse is it's a stupid error--

Comment: They are still the same values. For example `20.57 == 2.057e+01`.

Answer (score 0):

Values did not change, it's just a different representation.
`e+x` means `*10^x` (ten to power of x).
For example: 20.57 is same as `2.057e+01`, same as `0.2075e+02`. This representation is usually convenient for small numbers (e.g 0.0001 turns to `1e+04`) or large numbers (e.g 100000 turns to `1e+05`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x)
```